# iff $E\Bigl(|X_1|\log ({1+|X_1|)}\Bigr)<\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

**Question**: $X_n$'s are ***i.i.d*** then
$$E\Bigl(\sup_{n\geq 1} \frac{|X_n|}{n}\Bigr)<\infty \iff E\Bigl(|X_1|\log ({1+|X_1|)}\Bigr)<\infty$$

**My attempt**: for $\Rightarrow$ part, because $\limsup \frac{|X_n|}{n} \leq \sup_{n\geq 1} \frac{|X_n|}{n}$ a.s. from which I get $\limsup \frac{|X_n|}{n} < \infty$ a.s. implying $X_1 \in L_1$. But the question says something stronger.

**Motivation**:

(1)
$$0<p<1 \hspace{10pt} \text{then}\hspace{10pt} E\Bigl(\sup_{n\geq 1} \frac{|X_n|}{n^{1/p}}\Bigr)<\infty \iff X_1 \in L_1$$

(2)

$$1<p<\infty \hspace{10pt} \text{then}\hspace{10pt} E\Bigl(\sup_{n\geq 1} \frac{|X_n|}{n^{1/p}}\Bigr)<\infty \iff X_1 \in L_p$$

These two problems I was able to solve but then I saw a comment saying "what about the case $p=1$? Although it's much complicated to show, it turns out that...". I tried a lot but could not crack it. Any idea/hint/help? Thank you,

Comment: Any source? Hint?

Answer (score 4):

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $S_n=\sum_{k\le n}X_k$. Then $n^{-1}S_n$ is a reversed MTG and so, using [Doob's maximal inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality#Further_inequalities),

\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}\sup_{n}\frac{|X_n|}{n}&\le 2\mathsf{E}\sup_{n}\frac{|S_n|}{n} \\
&\le \frac{2e}{e-1}(1+\mathsf{E}|X_1|\ln^+|X_1|) \\
&\le \frac{2e}{e-1}(1+\mathsf{E}|X_1|\ln(1+|X_1|)) \\
&<\infty,
\end{align}

where $\ln^+(\cdot)=\ln(\cdot)\vee 0$.

($\Rightarrow$) Let $Y_n=1+|X_n|$. Then $Y_n\ge 1$ a.s., $\mathsf{E}\sup_n Y_n/n<\infty$, and

$$
\mathsf{E}|X_1|\ln(1+|X_1|)=\mathsf{E}Y_1\ln(Y_1)-\mathsf{E}\ln(Y_1).
$$

The second term is finite because $\mathsf{E}Y_1<\infty$ and

\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}Y_1\ln(Y_1)&=\int_1^\infty(\ln(y)+1)\mathsf{P}(Y_1>y)\,dy \\
&=\int_1^{\infty}\ln(y)\mathsf{P}(Y_1>y)\,dy+[\mathsf{E}Y_1-1].\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

The second term of \eqref{1} is finite. Let $K\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $Y_1\ge K-1$ a.s. and $\mathsf{P}(Y_1<K)>0$. Then $\sup_n Y_n/n\ge K-1$ a.s. and the first term is also finite because

\begin{align}
\infty&>\mathsf{E}\sup_n\frac{Y_n}{n}\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathsf{P}\!\left(\sup_n\frac{Y_n}{n}\ge k\right) \\
&=(K-1)+\sum_{k=K}^\infty \mathsf{P}\!\left(\sup_n\frac{Y_n}{n}\ge k\right) \\
&\ge^1 (K-1)+C_K\sum_{k=K}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf{P}(Y_1\ge nk),
\end{align}

where $C_K\equiv \prod_{k=K}^\infty \mathsf{P}(Y_1\le k)>0$), and

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf{P}(Y_1\ge nk)<^2\infty \Leftrightarrow \int_1^{\infty}\ln(y)\mathsf{P}(Y_1>y)\,dy <\infty.\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

The RHS of \eqref{2} converges iff

$$
\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty \mathsf{P}(Y_1>xy)\,dxdy <\infty.
$$

By changing variables $u=x$ and $v=xy$, the latter becomes

$$
\int_1^\infty\int_1^v\frac{1}{u}\mathsf{P}(Y_1>v)\,dudv=\int_1^\infty \ln(v)\mathsf{P}(Y_1>v)\,dv 
$$

which is the LHS of \eqref{2}.

---

$^1$ For $k\ge K$,

\begin{align}
&P\!\left(\sup_n\frac{Y_n}{n}>k\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\!\left(\left\{\bigcap_{1\le i<n}Y_i\le ik\right\} \cap \{Y_{n}>nk\}\right) \\
&\qquad\quad=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathsf{P}(Y_1\le ik)\mathsf{P}(Y_1> nk)\ge C_K\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf{P}(Y_1>nk).
\end{align}

---

$^2$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf{P}(Y_1\ge nk)\le (K-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf{P}(Y_1\ge n)+\sum_{k=K}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf{P}(Y_1\ge nk).
$$

Comment: I appreciate your effort and time. However I do not know Doob inequality. Give me couple of days. Once my qualifier is over I'll go through your proof step by step. Once again thank you.